# How is ball_pos calculated

Tags: 2d, godot, pong

I'm new to game development and I'm trying to build my first Pong game on the Godot engine. the tutorial I'm following is given below.

[Simple Pong Game](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/learning/step_by_step/simple_2d_game.html)

What I don't understand is the line:

```
ball_pos += direction * ball_speed * delta
```

**How is the new ball position being calculated?**

As far as I know, `delta` is the time elapsed in seconds (float) since the `last _process()` call.

**Also, why is the direction vector set to `(1.0, 0.0)`?**

I'm looking for a clear explanation since the tutorial doesn't explain much. Thank you.

Comment: Direction * Speed * DeltaTime = Velocity * DeltaTime = DeltaPosition

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` operator adds the right hand operand to the left hand operand.
So the line is equivalent to

```
ball_pos = ball_pos + direction*ball_speed*delta
```

So `direction*ball_speed*delta` is the offset of the new position compared to the old position. It's the distance the ball travelled during this frame. `direction*ball_speed` is the speed of the ball combined with its direction, so it's a vector. Direction is a so called unit vector, so its length is one. This represents the velocity of the ball in `(some distance-unit)/second`. If you multiply this by the time that passed since the last update you have the change in position in this frame.

To learn more about this I recommend researching the basics of linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly assumptions based off what I've seen for similar variables and formulas, but `ball_pos` is probably a vector (so it has a `direction`, hence multiplying by `direction` to get it's direction). `ball_speed` is likely velocity, so you need to know how far it travels/elapsed time, and `delta` is likely the elapsed time between calculations.

That with the `+=` basically says where was I, what direction did I go in and how fast did I go over the previous time frame, now where did that get me to.

Direction is set to `(#, 0)` because presumably it's not an x, y, z direction but just x, basically is it facing left or right (or up and down depending on what movement you're looking for).